# Reproduce audio files one after another

Tags: jquery, html, firefox, audio

I'm using HTML5 audio tag to play audio files one after another, but my routine seems to crash Firefox. It only works when I add an alert().

I have a routine in PHP which checks every 2 seconds if another application has sent new events to the server, if so, I write the name of the new event on the screen. Some of these events have audio files related to them (they can be different sounds), so when the event arrives the audio file has to be played.

I have this routine:

When the event arrives I call this function: playSound(sound_name);

```
    function playSound(sound_name){
        if (!current_sound){
            current_sound = true;
            $("#audio-player")[0].src = "../snd/"+sound_name;
            //$("#audio-player")[0].load();
            $("#audio-player")[0].play();
        }
        else {
            //alert(sound_name);
            playSound(sound_name);
        }
    }
```

The variable "current_sound" is set to false when the audio_player fires the "ended" event of the audio tag. I attatched a function to this event so everytime it's fired it sets the variable current_sound to false.

The problem with all this code is that it only works with that alert inside the function playSound(). If I comment it Firefox crashes and starts saying the js script is taking too long to complete (one of theirs js scripts, not mine).

I've searched a lot, but I've only found examples about how to reproduce a given list of files which is not useful in my case 'cause I don't know which files will be played beforehand.

Any suggestions?

Comment: The entire "audio" element of this question (and the HTML5 element) could be extracted out, and this could be made into an actual Javascript question.

Answer (score 1):

You have a trivial recursive call. The `alert` merely adds a delay and "breaks" that chain of execution, allowing threads elsewhere to get a word in edgeways. Presumably you have code elsewhere setting `current_sound` to `false`.

Instead of attempting to "wait" like this, use a callback function — wherever you're doing `current_sound = false`, instead do the `.play()` stuff.

Answer (score 0):

After the first call, `current_sound` will be set to true. This will cause the else branch to be taken every time, which calls the function again. This results in endless recursion.

Comment: @Lightness Races in Orbit Thanks. I understand I should do what I do inside the playSound() function inside the function I'm setting current_sound to false (which is the callback function when the "ended" event is fired). But what happens if I have 5 events waiting for their sounds to play? That's the part I don't understand how to tell the callback function which sound is next.

Comment: @user1132585: `$("#audio-player")[0]` is next.